# Maximum of $P$ in the disk $|z|=1$ depending on co-efficients

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $P(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\ldots+a_mz^m$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients such that $a_m\neq 0, a_n\neq 0$ and $n>m$. Prove that
$$\max_{|z|=1}\{|P(z)|\}\ge\sqrt{2|a_ma_n|+\sum_{k=m}^{n} |a_k|^2}$$
A problem from my Calculus exam, could someone help me with it? I have no idea how to start. Thanks.